# VS Pro 2012 Schema Sql Compare TimeOut

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, schema

I did a SQL Schema Compare using VS 2012 and when I click on Update I get this error:

```
Starting rebuilding table [dbo].[Claims]...
(46,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

I generated the change script and added:

```
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

Then ran the updated script. `I received different errors about DB objects already existing in the target DB.`

I looked at VS 2012 options but couldn't find any which allows me to increase the timeout for SQL Schema updates.